# XCode 4.2 : when app crashes, threads rarely display callstack

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, callstack

Since I've installed the last xCode (my previous one was the 3.xx), a have hard times to debug my crashing apps. Indeed, the callstack is often empty. And the displayed method is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"MyAppDelegate");
    [pool drain];
    return retVal;
}
```

Ex :
[image: Empty call stack !]

Have anyone noticed this ? It was working perfectly on the same project with previous XCode. Is there any solution ?

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373858/easy-way-to-print-current-stack-trace-of-an-app/5037433#5037433

Comment: And check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting *Exception Breakpoint* on Breakpoint panel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow ! It works for this crash. Thanks for the magic trick, but it seems too simple after reading the links above...

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you can change the number of items displayed in the stack frames view by dragging the slider at the bottom of the view.

Comment: cooool ! I never noticed it before