# ShareKit for iPhone randomly crashing

Tags: iphone, sharekit

I am having some issues with ShareKit for the iPhone.  I have everything I need(Twitter, Facebook, and Email mainly) working great for sending a URL.  In another portion of my app however, I am trying to implement the ability to share a small bit of text.  When I try to open Facebook when sharing this text, it opens the Facebook screen quickly and then it disappears.  Also, the app periodically crashes when I try to share the text, but never for the URL.  It seem strange for me.

I am not very experienced with things like crash logs and debugging but if anyone can direct me to the information provided by xcode when the app crashes that could potentially provide help to those expert programmers out there, I will definitely provide it.

EDIT: I just wanted to say that I copied the SHConfig file into the sample project and everything seems to work fine from there so it must be a problem with my code. This is what it is showing after the crash:

```
#0  0x028f0903 in objc_msgSend
#1  0x07540f70 in ??
#2  0x0276bf29 in __CFXNotificationPost_old
#3  0x026eb26a in _CFXNotificationPostNotification
#4  0x0019ec8a in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
#5  0x007c11b7 in -[UIInputViewTransition postNotificationsForTransitionStart]
#6  0x007c1651 in -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:]
#7  0x007b8728 in -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:]
#8  0x00507403 in -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews]
#9  0x005079d0 in -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
#10 0x0011204e in -[SHKFormFieldCell setSelected:animated:] at SHKFormFieldCell.m:116
#11 0x004b29cb in -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]
#12 0x004a924d in -[UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:]
#13 0x0011051a in -[SHKFormController viewDidAppear:] at SHKFormController.m:122
#14 0x004f2a5a in -[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:]
#15 0x006d827f in -[UIWindowController transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:]
#16 0x004c8905 in -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:]
#17 0x0046f499 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
#18 0x0046f32b in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
#19 0x047a6db0 in run_animation_callbacks
#20 0x047a6c6f in CA::timer_callback
#21 0x02774f73 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
#22 0x027765b4 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer
#23 0x026d2dd9 in __CFRunLoopRun
#24 0x026d2350 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#25 0x026d2271 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#26 0x02f7e00c in GSEventRunModal
#27 0x02f7e0d1 in GSEventRun
#28 0x0044daf2 in UIApplicationMain
#29 0x00002690 in main at main.m:15
```

Comment: I use PinkelStar to implement native sharing. Works quite well, and provides extra stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the problem, but have no idea how to fix it for what I was trying to do.  I was trying to launch ShareKit from a button in a UIAlertView.  Apparently, Sharekit needed to be launched from a simple button on the screen, or a UIActionView.  I went with a UIActionView and now it works.

Comment: I noticed that too.  I think it has something to do with the AlertView dismissing

Answer (score 1):

Hey Rob, try finding where the crash is occurring by using this method:
[How to add a breakpoint to objc_exception_throw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw)

Then post back the Object/method that is causing the crash.

You may also want to try copying your SHKConfig.h file from your project into the example project provided in ShareKit to see if the crash still occurs.  If it does, then it's a problem with Sharekit, if it does not, the problem is within your own app.

Comment: I followed the instructions in your link and when the app crashed, it kicked me back to xcode.  I still don't quite know what I am looking for now though.  In the lower left it reads "GDB: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"