# NSRangeException in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

We are using `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` method to retrieve a cell at specific index path. `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` will return an object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range. However repeating calls to `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` causes NSRange exception. What can be the reason?

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableview_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
```

code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CustomCell *cell = nil;
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customcell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
}
ImageCache *imageCache = [[ImageCache alloc]initWithUrl:sentCard.sentImage];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache fetchImageFromCache];
    if (cachedImage!=nil) {
        cell.cardImage.image = [Utility scaleImageToSize:cell.cardImage.frame.size image:cachedImage];
        [cell.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
    else {
        imageCache.cacheDelegate = self;
        imageCache.cacheDuration = 24.0;
        [imageCache fetchImage];
    }
return cell;
}
```

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239666/nsrangeexception-call-stack-not-showing-line-number

Comment: Would you show your `cellForRowATIndexPath:` method?

Comment: you are not returning any cell.. ;) its a typo, not reason of your error though

Comment: @Jesly Varghese Sorry, It was a mistake in editing post.

Comment: please post the complete error message.

Comment: Its probably an array causing the crash, and its no where in the code you have provided here... Please give the context for `NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableview_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a cell that is not being created yet. For example, that should crash on the first cell (index 0). You should ask for a cell (aka `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) once the table as being populated.

Comment: UITableView documentation specifies that -  (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath will return an object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range. So if there is no cell at the specified index path, it will return nil. However here call to (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath produce NSRangeException.

Comment: What are you returning on `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: It won't cause a crash/range exception, gracefully returns nil

Comment: Where is the location of the crash?