# How I can backtrack to the first failed in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my apps crash to this part of code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

@autoreleasepool {
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    return retVal;
}
}
```

So, where in xcode 4 i can see list of things that the program did before he goes to this point, In clear I want a know at what line the program crash in my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing that then it's highly likely your program has terminated due to an uncaught exception. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw) to see how to set a breakpoint in `objc_exception_throw` which will then help as you'll be dropped right into the code that's causing the exception to be thrown.

Comment: This is the way to go.  NSZombie is also helpful but not directly the issue behind your specific question.

Comment: Indeed. It's getting to be the defacto thing people say when people have a crash - "Turn on zombies". Sure, in my opinion you should always (in general) dev with it on, but it's not likely going to be of help here.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable Zombies? To do it do the following:

1) Click on your app name(next to the Run and Stop buttons on top)

2) Click "Edit Scheme..."

3) In "Memory Management" put a tick on "Enable Zombie Objects"

Or you can get there by clicking "Product" --> "Edit Scheme..."

Hope it helps