# What's the difference between objc_exception_throw and [NSException raise]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exception

One useful tip I've been using for XCode is [adding breakpoints on exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw).

I was wondering why we need to add two breakpoints--one for `objc_exception_throw` and one for `[NSException raise]`.

What cases do one cover that the other doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only use a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`. The method `-[NSException raise]` calls `objc_exception_throw`, so `objc_exception_throw` covers all cases that `-[NSException raise]` covers. The other way around is not true: The `@throw` directive is compiled to call `objc_exception_throw` directly. This method shows the difference:

```
- (void)throwAndCatch
{
    @try {
        NSException *exception = [[NSException alloc] initWithName:@"Test" 
                                                            reason:@"test" 
                                                          userInfo:nil];
        @throw exception;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Caught");
    }
}
```

When calling `-throwAndCatch`, a breakpoint on `-[NSException raise]` has no effect, while a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what from Apple's Documentation about Exception:

> An important difference between @throw and raise is that the latter
>   can be sent only to an NSException object whereas @throw can take
>   other types of objects as its argument (such as string objects). Cocoa
>   applications should @throw only NSException objects.

Which means if you are implementing a `Cocoa applciation project` and if you strictly follow that @throw only `NSExeption` objects they are the same.

reference: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/RaisingExceptions.html)