# Unknown exception and crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

My application crashes when I try to scroll the tableview very fast or reload the data from remote. Everything seems to be working fine, when I let the remote fetch happen first and then scroll the tableview. I have no idea what the crash log below means. It just works fine sometimes and crashes sometime.

```
Incident Identifier: 710A120C-97E3-45C8-A7B2-E6A7BD98BC1A
CrashReporter Key:   8bd54d8428128b9e6b8c04d59b86c40cccf33457
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         MyApp [5294]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B6ED5B19-B8D7-4146-90A2-F709AE35292F/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-02-26 16:45:27.693 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c3f658a _cache_getImp + 10
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c3f6fa0 lookUpMethod + 24
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c3f81e2 class_respondsToSelector + 26
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3470a750 objectIsKindOfClass + 32
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3470a49c __handleUncaughtException + 64
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c3fba46 _objc_terminate() + 126
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3be48118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3be481b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3be49626 __cxa_rethrow + 90
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c3fb9b0 objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3465129c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x346510c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x3822f336 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x3656d2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  MyApp                       0x000910a2 0x44000 + 315554
15  MyApp                       0x0004668c 0x44000 + 9868

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8df5d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c81ad22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c816374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8dee30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8defd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x346df2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x346de02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34651238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x346510c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x3a650390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8dee30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8defd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x346df2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x346de02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34651238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x346510c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x34f9e888 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x3502222c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8efd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83dad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83d7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83d680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8dee30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8defd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x346df2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x346de02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34651238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x346510c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x34f755be -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x35018c40 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   MyApp                       0x0016b900 0x44000 + 1210624
9   Foundation                      0x3502222c __NSThread__main__ + 968
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8dee30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8defd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x346df2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x346de02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34651238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x346510c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x34f755be -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x35018c40 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   MyApp                       0x000e63d0 0x44000 + 664528
9   Foundation                      0x3502222c __NSThread__main__ + 968
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8ef594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x346e3474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8dee30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8defd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x346df2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x346de02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34651238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x346afc46 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   MyApp                       0x00115d7e 0x44000 + 859518
7   Foundation                      0x3502222c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8efd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83dad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83d7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83d680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8efd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83dad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83d7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83d680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8ef08c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c840afc _pthread_cond_wait + 644
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c840870 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x38625df6 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 102
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x38738532 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 78
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x3874b030 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8ef08c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c840afc _pthread_cond_wait + 644
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c84acf8 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x386cb6dc JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 140
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x386cb620 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 140
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x3874b030 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8dee30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8defd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x346df2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x346de02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34651238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x346510c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x3a6eaccc WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 140
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x3874b030 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c8480de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c847fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c8efd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83dad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83d7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c83d680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000004    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x0042c714
    r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x0042c744      r7: 0x0042c764
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x0042c6c8     r10: 0x3e3a2188     r11: 0x00000002
    ip: 0x00000171    sp: 0x0042c6d0      lr: 0x3c81ad27      pc: 0x3c8df5d0
  cpsr: 0x60000010
```

I would be really happy if anybody could explain me what this crash log could relate to and how I could solve it. Many many thanks to all those who are willing to help others.

Comment: It looks like an uncaught exception. [Add an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1164675/620197) to help track down the code.

Comment: Can you symbolicate `0x3c8df5d0` please and post back.

Comment: If you are wondering what trojanfoe means look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports I did scratch my head for a minute after reading his comment but after looking at this link I know exactly what he meant. But yeah doing this would help.

Comment: I'm not sure it will help actually, as it's not in the app code anyway, it's in `libsystem_kernel.dylib`.

Comment: The problem is that neither do I have .app file nor .dsym. What can I do in this situation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me that it's dangling pointer, and you're sending message to it.
As MikeD said, use breakpoint on exception if it can help. But it's not 100% reliable since you get a SIGSEGV and not a SIGABRT. And the exception throw is not really the cause of the crash, just a border effect.

Edit

Ok: In your log crash, it says that libsystem_kernel.dylib has crashed in a kevent call. That won't help you since this is private and opaque, and you can be 100% sure this lib do its job well. This can appears because you have used (unintentionally) a space memory where you should not write into. Like with a dangling pointer. Let's say you have allocated memory to 0x2000 and you have a pointer pointing to this memory, if you freed the memory but still using this pointer to this address, if someone else (like libsystem_kernel) use it, and you change some data in the same time (because of your dangling pointer). Then the other side will use data corrupted, and some random behavior will occur. That's why if you analyze literally your crash log, you'll do wrong statement. Because kevent from libSystem is stable.

By the way you have thread 1 who crashed, but look into thread 0, it was trying to raise an exception too, but it didn't get time to do it. This can occur because of data corrupted too.

That's why I recommend you to make another crash, and compare it to this one. If the crash log are the same, then i was totally wrong. If the crash log are different, this is a dangling pointer.

Comment: It's more complex than that as it crashes here `0x3c8df5d0 kevent64 + 24` not in `objc_msg_send()`.

Comment: trojanfoe, this is exactly what i said. Insane-36 want the cause of the crash, not what the crash really means. If it crashed on libsystem_kernel.dylib call, that doesn't mean it's libsystem_kernel library responsible. By the way i'm not a soothSayer, but i'm 100% sure GCD and libsystem_kernel are OK. insane36 should make another crash and test if the crash log will output differently.

Comment: @MrBonjour I also want to know what the crash really means not just the reason to the crash. If you could explain it in some simple language, that would be more helpful.