# What could cause this crash?

Tags: ios, iphone, crash-reports

I occasionally get a crash report which looks like to following:

```
Incident Identifier: 9E8A29CD-C473-41BE-9018-2DFEC530612B
CrashReporter Key:   bee45cc2c49f3c1a0c3793b1a519a04012b8dffe
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:             dominicanorder [17420]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/2154A91A-04D2-4F93-A116-DA276DEB6E90/dominicanorder.app/dominicanorder
Identifier:          org.idoms.dominicanorder
Version:             232 (1.2.4)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-01-13 09:03:58.173 +0000
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x382ec7f0 objc_release + 16
1   UIKit                           0x30517a24 -[UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer dealloc] + 44
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x382fab06 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab1650 CFRelease + 552
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab91dc -[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 60
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x382fab06 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x382ec002 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 354
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab497c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
8   UIKit                           0x302ec248 _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 32
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2db4c1ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2db49b6c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 280
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2db49eae __CFRunLoopRun + 726
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
14  GraphicsServices                0x327a827e GSEventRunModal + 134
15  UIKit                           0x30358044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
16  dominicanorder                  0x000d09ce 0xcc000 + 18894
17  dominicanorder                  0x000d0984 0xcc000 + 18820

Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3889b83c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x387dc210 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x387dbf96 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388aec7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388aec7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3889ba8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3889b888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2db4b7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2db49ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2cb37584 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 124
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2cb2b99c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916c1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916b8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3889badc semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x387da428 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 172
2   MediaToolbox                    0x2efa083c fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1752
3   CoreMedia                       0x2e0df234 figThreadMain + 192
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916c1a _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916b8a _pthread_start + 98
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388aec7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388aec7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388aec7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388aec7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3889ba8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3889b888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2db4b7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2db49ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2e4ef2f2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x2e564c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916c1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916b8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388ae440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2db4f680 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916c1a _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916b8a _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  WebThread
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388adf38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916224 _pthread_cond_wait + 536
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38917040 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   WebCore                         0x35cc0be2 SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 690
4   WebCore                         0x35c9895e WebRunLoopUnlockInternal(AutoreleasePoolOperation) + 162
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2db4c1ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2db49b6c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 280
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4c44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
9   WebCore                         0x35c97266 RunWebThread(void*) + 414
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916c1a _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916b8a _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388adf38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916224 _pthread_cond_wait + 536
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38917040 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ead9eb0 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 104
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ead9cdc JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ead73a0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916c1a _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916b8a _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 14 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388adf38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916224 _pthread_cond_wait + 536
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38917000 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ec75236 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 74
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ec75290 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 48
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ead73a0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916c1a _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916b8a _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 15 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3889ba8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3889b888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2db4b7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2db49ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dab4a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x35cdfd5a WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 250
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ead73a0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916c1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38916b8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38914c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000004    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x001b56f0
    r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x001b5760
    r8: 0x3a748170    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x3a747f40
    ip: 0x00000171    sp: 0x001b56d0      lr: 0x387dc215      pc: 0x3889b83c
  cpsr: 0x60000010
```

What could cause this crash?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322198/how-to-read-crash-log-how-to-find-why-the-app-crashes-in-system-library-what-m

Comment: Wow. Let me just get out my crystal ball and divine from it the code that is causing this crash.

Comment: I was hoping there was something in the pattern which would give a clue. I haven't be able to find a way to reproduce the error when debugging.

Comment: You are over-releasing an object, that is likely inside an `NSArray`. Are you using ARC? Did you try running static analyzer?

Comment: Same type question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092522/unknown-exception-and-crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to enable breakpoints to all see below

[image]

In this way you should be able to identify the bad instruction before sigabrt signal.

I hope this could help

Comment: Yes, I would like to, but haven't found a way to reproduce the crash. So it happens occasionally, but never when I have the debugger attached. I was hoping there was something in the report that could identify a possible cause and I could try focus my attempts to reproduce the error.

Comment: Are you using a UIWebView? in that case it could cause your app crashes when try to loading some contents, especially pdf documents or complex pages that use a lot of javascript code inside. This problem is fixed through iOS updates, but still exist

Comment: Yes, I do. The App syncs, and then (in the background, but naturally on the main UIThread) loads the content to calculate the required height for showing the article in a UITableViewCell later and cache any images for faster loading. Maybe I should look in that direction then.

Comment: If you confirm the problem associated to UIWebView, you could try to work around replacing the default user agent of UIWebView with the user agent used from Safari App ( that yes, are different ). In case use this: 

" NSDictionary *userAgentReplacement = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:<SAFARI USER AGENT>, @"UserAgent", nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userAgentReplacement];"

( it's allowed for publish on App Store )

I've used this trick to solve an old problem, with success

Comment: Exception breakpoints do NOT help with this crash, since it is not an exception!

Comment: Thanks! I have taken out the background web view rendering, and just submitted an update to the App Store as I had few small bug fixes. As soon as it is released I will be able to see if this particular crash will cease, and if so, will try your solution.