# -[NSThread _nq:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1fdf5040 (lldb)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, iphone-5

```
    -[NSThread _nq:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1fdf5040
(lldb)
```

This is one crash i am getting while my app enter in back ground. In iphone 4 it was working. it happening in iphone 5. what is the possibility and how we can solve it?

Comment: from the information you give we can only analyze that you seem to have a memory problem while using NSThread. Since _nq seems to be private Apple Api I assume this happens while doing something else - can you please post the stack trace or your method where this crash occurs?

Comment: where i get stack trace? all it happening is whenever my app enter background it getting crash with the same reason

Comment: What is your app doing when entering in the background? Are you doing any background operations like network calls, audio session etc? Add breakpoint for objc_exception_throw in your XCode. Procedure to do this can be [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14767076/1407017). By this you can check the stack trace when app crashes

Answer (score 0):

you have to run your project Zombies instrument.For find errors at which class or which object. Hit Command+I to profile the app and select the Zombies instrument (you must be running on the simulator). If you get a zombie, you can display the entire memory history (each retain/release) for that object, which is immensely helpful in tracking down errors.

see this for detail of Zombies

http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

[How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

First up all thanks for the helping mind.

I solved my problem my self and sharing for you. For me it happend some thread running in the background. while app entering in the background that thread losing its destination. That made app crash.

Some how i did thread wait until done is NO everywhere and everything works fine.