# Crash while using Autolayout

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, autolayout

I have an app that works very will without Autolayout. After I introduced Autolayout and made sure all the "Constraints not satisfying" type messages disappear from the console log, I can load my view on both 3.5 and 4.0 retina displays. When I try to add a modalview, the app crashes with the following. No way to debug ... please help.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x01be209b objc_msgSend + 15
1   Foundation                      0x009c4795 -[NSISVariable shouldBeIntegral] + 57
2   Foundation                      0x009b8a58 -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 546
3   Foundation                      0x009b90d4 -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:] + 382
4   Foundation                      0x009be0e0 -[NSISEngine removeConstraintWithMarker:] + 315
5   Foundation                      0x009c87ee -[NSLayoutConstraint _removeFromEngine:] + 277
6   UIKit                           0x01322721 __72-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _removeRelevantConstraintsFromEngine:]_block_invoke_0 + 363
7   Foundation                      0x009bd0b3 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 57
8   UIKit                           0x01322579 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _removeRelevantConstraintsFromEngine:] + 109
9   UIKit                           0x00e254d4 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 766
10  UIKit                           0x00e25133 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 70
11  UIKit                           0x00e9e935 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 634
12  UIKit                           0x00ea0f13 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 107
13  UIKit                           0x00e1cd66 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 237
14  UIKit                           0x00e1cf04 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 68
15  QuartzCore                      0x007297d8 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 284
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x029c0014 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x029b07d5 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 296
18  CoreFoundation                  0x01d51af5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1925
19  CoreFoundation                  0x01d50f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
20  CoreFoundation                  0x01d50e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
21  GraphicsServices                0x02bf77e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
22  GraphicsServices                0x02bf7668 GSEventRun + 104
23  UIKit                           0x00ddeffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
24  LMClient-1.0                    0x0000291d main + 141 (main.m:16)
25  LMClient-1.0                    0x00002845 start + 53
```

Comment: Try to set exception breakpoint to see on which line the app crashes?

Comment: It doesnt crash at a certain line ... just crashes abruptly. For the time being, I have assumed that Autolayout is buggy, and am resorting to the age old if(4.0inchDisplay) ... type stuff in my viewDidLoad

Comment: Add a global breakpoint in XCode - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw for examples on how to do that, the XCode 4 example is a few comments in.  Review your affected screens in the storyboard too, it sounds like there are still some important constraints missing.