# Exc Bad Access on dismiss of view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, exc-bad-access

I have two view controller e.g. controller A and Controller B
i am presenting a controller B on click of a button on controller A by using this code

```
- (IBAction)CategoriesTapped:(id)sender {
    CategoriesViewController  * category=[[CategoriesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CategoriesViewController" bundle:Nil];
    [self presentViewController:category animated:YES completion:^
     {
         NSLog(@"Loaded...");
     }
     ];
}
```

and i am dismissing this controller on click of button on controller B as :

```
- (IBAction)CloseTapped:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
     {         
        NSLog(@"dismissed...");
     }
     ];

}
```

It works fine the first time, but when I try to present this controller again, the app crashes with exc_bad_access. I can't figure out what the problem actually is so please can anybody help me out of this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: there is no log on the console....

Comment: How do you know it crashes, then?

Comment: app just stops a some point near "0x16d009b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi" saying exc bad access and also when i viewed system log queries it shows "fill rate for application"com.---------" development is 80%"

Comment: Its not crashing because of above code, since it is working fine for me.Reason for crashing is different. It is crashing because you are trying to access some object which is not present or is deallocated.

Comment: declare your category into .h file or under @interface in .m file, hope it will help.

Comment: @Bharat What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: @Bharat now this is creating crash when i dismiss view controller

Comment: To know what the actual problem is you can set Exception break point in Xcode check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw (2nd answer)

Answer (score 1):

Look like zombie.
Run profiler with searching for zombies.