# apps runs on iPhone 5 but not on iPhone 4s get error SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, signals, sigabrt

When I run my app on a iPhone 5 I get no errors but when I run it on a iphone 4S it freezes when you touch a tab and then excode outputs:

```
"Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" on the "return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }" line.
```

In my `Main.m` I don't know what I have done wrong. I tried to clean up code in my app but I don't know how to find what's making the error.

Here is my main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
0x2f794ce7 0x2f794acb 0x344b5283 0x32036a41 0x1b7a5 0x3a141ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "
```

Comment: main.m is irrelevant. Set a breakpoint where you touch the tab and step through the code.

Comment: Post the crash and any system logging output.

Comment: here is the error i get 0x2f794ce7 0x2f794acb 0x344b5283 0x32036a41 0x1b7a5 0x3a141ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 4):

```
"0x2f794ce7 0x2f794acb 0x344b5283 0x32036a41 0x1b7a5 0x3a141ab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) "
```

That isn't the crash log.   Nor is it a backtrace.  You've posted very little evidence.

However, the above is helpful.   Go into the Xcode debugger and create an Exception Breakpoint.  You'll want to "stop on Objective-C exceptions".

When it breaks, post the backtrace of where it stops.   Main thread?  Background thread?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information due to the fact `SIGABRT` is a very generic name for an error but here is a link that describes what errors in ios are and how you can read them

[iOS Errors](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

Comment: SIGABRT is the easiest of errors to solve too :3 so read this, do what it says to read the error and then re-edit your question with those logs and we can help you

Comment: thank you i will try that and i do get this error if this helps " 0x2f794ce7 0x2f794acb 0x344b5283 0x32036a41 0x1b7a5 0x3a141ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)"

Comment: In the link, there is a section about exception breakpoints, read about that and how to implement them, do that and re-run. The compiler might stop the code at the point of the crash and you wont see all of those object addresses

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app, or some component of it, is built for 64 bit only. Check your build settings.

As for your crash, The info you describe is not helpful in tracking down the crash.

You want to to 2 things:

1. Add exception breakpoints so your app stops on the line that is triggering the crash (see the link at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw))
2. Go to the stack trace navigator and drag the slider all the way to the right, to show the maximum level of detail in your stack traces. Then you should be able to see the line on which you are crashing.

Comment: The app would't link.

Comment: @bbum, what app? You're not the original poster, right? Are you saying that the OPs app won't link, or that yours won't? If the OPs, what makes you think that?

Comment: If part of the app was built 64 bit only, it could not possibly run as a 32 bit app, which the meager crash information does indicate.

Comment: Plus, the OP indicates that the app runs fine on the iPhone 5, which is 32 bit, too...