# AsyncSocket crash on sleep mode for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, asyncsocket

[image]I am using robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket for async socket, when my iPad goes into background state i disconnect and close all the ports, but some times when iPad awakes from sleep it crashes, happened same with simulator when mac goes to sleep mode. Once i got crash log as [AsyncSocket close] unrecognized instance send to selector.

I am not able to find a solution for this, can any one help me on this. Below is my code for disconnecting.

```
- (void) enterBackground
{

  if (self.discoveryUdpSocket!=nil)
 {
    self.discoveryUdpSocket.delegate = nil;
    [self.discoveryUdpSocket close];
 }

  self.discoveryUdpSocket.delegate = nil;
  self.discoveryUdpSocket = nil;

}
```

[image: Crash report 1]

[image: Crash report 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to extend time when entering background mode to allow socket framework complete its job?

I mean to add in the app delegate a method:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
        bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            NSLog(@"Times up!");
            [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];
        // Let the async socket to complete its job and finally close the connection
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSLog(@"Finishing job and closing async socket, time remaining=%f", [app backgroundTimeRemaining]);
            // Calling your background routine
            [self enterBackground];
            [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        });
}
```

This is a good way to complete important job just before app is suspended. You have max 180 secs.

Comment: Should i add this before or after the socket close method ?

Comment: Added a code that calls your method 'enterBackground'. Hope should work.

Comment: Show a log output when app crashes

Comment: I have added crash report to the question

Comment: @Prernachavan, thanks for report, but unfortunately it's useless, please symbolicate it, take a look i.e. here [Symbolicating an iOS crash log](https://coderwall.com/p/ezdcmg) or [Overview of iOS Crash Reporting](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1)

Comment: Hm, you said that it happens also on simulator, so try to add a breakpoint to objc_exception_throw to find out where and why exactly is exception raised. Additionally, you can use a try/catch statement.  [How to add a breakpoint to objc_exception_throw?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw)