# Building success then "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error" pops up

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8-beta3

I'm on the initial way of building a calculator. Currently, the code is doing nothing but printing the digits and Pi into the calculator's label when user taps them.

**1) Che Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel! = nil

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeing = false

    @IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton){
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeing {
            let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
            display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
        }

        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeing = true
    }

    @IBAction func performOperation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeing = false
        if let methematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
            if methematicalSymbol == "π" {
                display.text = String(M_PI) // M_PI
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

**2) UI**

The **touchDigit** function is linked to all the digit buttons as shown in the following figure. The **display** is the `UILable` while **performOperaton** is the PI button

[image]

**Problem**

When I build the code, Xcode first told me the building was success, However, before I could do anything, there is an error popped up as follow

[image]

**Error Log (copied from the debug area)**

```
2016-07-28 19:30:30.215343 Calculator[11671:208157] bundleid: com.Jeffery.Calculator, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2016-07-28 19:30:30.218796 Calculator[11671:208157] Created DB, header sequence number = 260
2016-07-28 19:30:30.767300 Calculator[11671:208178] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEvents, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-07-28 19:30:31.022078 Calculator[11671:208157] Created DB, header sequence number = 260
2016-07-28 19:30:31.350380 Calculator[11671:208157] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-07-28 19:30:31.388363 Calculator[11671:208159] subsystem: com.apple.FrontBoard, category: Common, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Maybe start by using `if let` instead of `!` on optionals.

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel! = nil. Why you are setting it to nil?

Comment: You cut the log at the most interesting part :( The next lines were the description of the exception, which in most cases tell you everything you need to know. Also, it is worthwhile to set an exception breakpoint - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: @Losiowaty I think the log I've cut off is (lldb)

Comment: @ldindu I figured it out my error, there are two connections attached  with the PI button to the viewControler (I should delete one). The code works fine with UILabel! = nil. Why is that?

Comment: If the question is solved, accept the answer that solved it, or post your own answer. If you have a new question, post a *new, different* question but don't change the meaning of this existing one. Thanks.

Comment: @EricD good points and make sense. I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out my error, there are two connections attached with the PI button to the viewControler (I should delete one).

Comment: For future reference, there is mention of an `NSException` being thrown.  This exception object will have valuable information in it which you need to read.  Try adding [this breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw) when using Xcode to see it when it's thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here: '@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel! = nil'. When you do something with 'display' property you try do it with nil. Just try delete '= nil' after declarating property. Or you can override view controller init method, but as for me, in this situation it is bad way.

Comment: Hi, I think that's a good point. I deleted the nil settings, AKA only the UILable!. But the error still exist (BTW, please excuse my late reply)