# XCode error Thread 1 : Signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, push-notification

I create an app with the Ionic Framework.

On IOS / XCode : 
I have an error that appear when I build (with succeed) my app on XCode. 
This error is on the main.m "Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT"

Someone know where did this error come from?
How to resolve it ?

In my all exceptions breakpoint "objc_exception_throw in libobjc.A.dylib" and "_cxa_thrpw in libc++abi.dylib"

This breakpoint emphasizes the line "[FIRApp configure]; " in my AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m

[Screen of my main.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1itT.png)

[Screen of AppDelagate+FirebasePlugin.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEEbu.jpg)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

This can be a lot of things happening, check:

- That your AppDelegate is called "AppDelegate" in this case.
- Default Storyboard
- Inside storyboard if you have a InitialViewController
- Activate breakpoint "AllExceptions" to see if you can have more information

Comment: Ok thanks !

I have in my all exceptions breakpoint "objc_exception_throw in libobjc.A.dylib" and "_cxa_thrw in libc++abi.dylib"

Comment: Have you tried this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw

Comment: Yes 
This breakpoint emphasizes the line "[FIRApp configure]; " in my AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m.
You can see the screen of it in my question.

Comment: I think it's a problem between Firebase and XCode because on Android device and Android Studio it works.

Comment: Yes because I know what is the problem but I can't solve it. 
Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Caroline care to share what your answer was?