# enable line numbers of stack trace in xcode console

Tags: xcode, stack-trace, line-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a breakpoint to objc_exception_throw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw)

I read this post [Stack trace or more info on unhandled exception in Xcode/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093999/stack-trace-or-more-info-on-unhandled-exception-in-xcode-iphone)

It seems like the chosen answer is the correct way, however the answerer doesn't tell you how to create the global breakpoints.

Does anyone know how I can create these break points and see the line number of my exceptions?