# NSCFData isResizable crash?

Tags: objective-c, ios, console, crash

I am currently getting this crash log in the console:

```
2011-08-23 19:18:40.064 App[1697:707] -[__NSCFData _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11f1c0
2011-08-23 19:18:40.075 App[1697:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11f1c0'
```

Does anyone know what this means? What could be the cause of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More likely than not, you've over-released some random object and, quite coincidentally, an instance of NSData (or CFData) has been allocated at the location of the now-gone object.

Run the Zombie detection instrument and see if that catches anything (search SO for NSZombie).

Alternatively, set a breakpoint on objc_exception_throw and that should show you where the message is being sent.  That may not provide enough context, though.

Comment: the problem ended up being I was setting an NSData object to a UIImageView, stupid me!

Comment: Hah!   That'll do it, too.   Glad you found it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be sending an invalid selector (isResizable) to an object, perhaps an NSData object? Do you have a stack trace to provide more information about where the crash is happening?

Comment: I only use NSData in the view controller where the crash is once and that is not called on startup. The crash happens on startup. How would I get the stack trace?

Comment: See [this older SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093999/stack-trace-or-more-info-on-unhandled-exception-in-xcode-iphone/1094096#1094096), including the comments from Brad Larson if you want to do this in Xcode 4

Comment: run it in instruments with zombie detection enabled. instruments can record all the ref counts for objects, which reduces the time it takes to identify zombies/lifetimes/sources to about a minute once reproduced.

Comment: the problem ended up being I was setting an NSData object to a UIImageView, stupid me!