# Getting exception in NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am having following code for getting image from the web:

```
 NSURL *ImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/image.jpg"];

 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: ImageURL];
```

I am getting following exception:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithCapacity:]: capacity (4294967295) is ridiculous'
```

If i remove the second  line of nsdata then exception is not occurring .Please give me the solution.

Comment: I guess he is referring to `NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: ImageURL];`

Comment: Please provide the correct URL. There seems to be an issue with the image.

Comment: Also try to use `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ImageURL];`.

Comment: It would help if you posted the stack trace.

Comment: Actually, the error message is quite funny. :)

Comment: I would suggest you have a URL problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url path may have space. So use like this

```
NSString *url=@"http://url/image.jpg";

url=[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441106/nsdata-nsurl-url-with-space-having-problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code piece from another SO question, [mbm30075's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473960/692507) as long as your image's size is small. If not, in order for the UI to be interactive, use asynchronous connection to download the image first with `NSURLConnection`